# Is there a Grep command to grep pound Sign (£), multiple grep options have tried none works

Tags: unix, grep

Have tried multiple grep options but yet to get any result, appreciate a quick help

```
grep -R '\£{' file | wc -l
grep -Fn '\£{' file | wc -l
```

sample input file:

```
£{334689900abcdefghij£{klmnopqrstuvwx
```

hexdump -c file

```
 0000000 a3 7b 33 33 34 36 38 39 39 30 30 61 62 63 64 65  |.{334689900abcde|
 0000010 66 67 68 69 6a a3 7b 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70 71 75 73  |fghij.{klmnopqus|
 0000020 74 75 76 77 78                                   |tuvwx|
```

Comment: nope, have tried that as well

Comment: Add output of `hexdump -C file` to your question.

Comment: the count  remains 0, though the file has £

Comment: Your file may be in a different encoding than that of your console. So please do provide a small sample file that you have a problem with by posting the output of `hexdump -C the-small-file` on it. Basically, a [mcve] is required to help you.

Comment: I have added the hexdump -C output now

Comment: @Linnea: The output of `hexdump -C` with a capital C is normally 78 characters wide.

Comment: sorry Cyrus had used small c earlier I think, anyways corrected it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Summary

Your source file appears to be in a different character set than your operating system.  You need to use a utility such as `iconv` to convert the source file to match the OS.

#### Details

Your `hexdump -C` output shows the pound sign as `A3`.  This is consistent with ISO-8859 which is common on Windows systems.  From `man iso-8859-1`:

```
   Oct   Dec   Hex   Char   Description
   ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   240   160   A0           NO-BREAK SPACE
   241   161   A1     ¡     INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK
   242   162   A2     ¢     CENT SIGN
   243   163   A3     £     POUND SIGN
   244   164   A4     ¤     CURRENCY SIGN
```

Modern Unix systems use UTF-8 and, [in UTF-8](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/), the pound sign is not `A3` it is `C2 A3`:

```
Code   char Hex     Name
U+00A2  ¢   c2 a2   CENT SIGN
U+00A3  £   c2 a3   POUND SIGN
U+00A4  ¤   c2 a4   CURRENCY SIGN
U+00A5  ¥   c2 a5   YEN SIGN
```

This may explain why `grep` fails to match.

#### Solution

The utility `file` will try to guess the encoding of a file.  It may be helpful to run

```
file yourfile
```

After that, run `iconv`:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf8 <yourfile >yourfileconverted
```

where you need to replace `ISO-8859-1` with your best guess for the encoding of the input file and `utf8` with the default encoding for your operating system.  Then, `grep` should work as expected:

```
grep £ yourfileconverted
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation can I use iconv for my file, can you please help

Comment: @Linnea The updated answer includes an example of using `iconv`.

Comment: that was indeed very helpful and works as expected John !!!, thanks